# unify code when getting highest value and lowest value

Tags: java

My IDE is giving me duplicate code warning and now I'm trying to find out is there any way to unify or find common abstraction for such two methods, that are quite similar in their structure, but do the opposite things? I couldn't figure out it myself. Thx

```
public double getLowestCurrencyRateInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> rates = getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency);
    double lowestRate = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Map<String, Double> ratesByDate : rates.values()){
        double baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency = ratesByDate.get(targetCurrency);
        if(baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency < lowestRate){
            lowestRate = baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency;
        }
    }
    return lowestRate;
}

public double getHighestCurrencyRateInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> rates = getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency);
    double highestRate = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for(Map<String, Double> ratesByDate : rates.values()){
        double baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency = ratesByDate.get(targetCurrency);
        if(baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency > highestRate){
            highestRate = baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency;
        }
    }
    return highestRate;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `keySet()` in those methods just to get the values later on? Couldn't you just use `valueSet()` instead?

Comment: You are completely right, I can use .values() instead and i will, but the original problem still persists

Comment: I've edited my answer just now, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is a lot of unnecessary code in there. You can achieve the same in much nicer way using Streams. It would looks something like this:

```
public double getHighestCurrencyRateInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency, String variant) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> rates = getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency);
    DoubleStream doubleStream = rates.values().stream()
                 .mapToDouble(entry -> entry.get(targetCurrency));
    OptionalDouble result = variant.equals("max") ? doubleStream.max() : doubleStream.min();
    return result.orElse(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with several of the previous answers, and believe that they could very well be used.

Personally, I would create one unified method to handle the common logic flow and then have two descriptive method calling this "common-logic-method"

Thereby I avoid having to deal with a boolean-flag as an argument (in this case a double-flag), I get the chance to express which name fits the method best, and finally I centralize all the logic flows in one method.

**Example:**

```
public double getLowestCurrencyRateInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
    return commonLogic(targetCurrency, getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency), Double.MAX_VALUE);
}

public double getHighestCurrencyRateInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency) {
    return commonLogic(targetCurrency, getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency), Double.MIN_VALUE);
}

private double commonLogic(String targetCurrency, Map<String, Map<String, Double>> rates, double rate) {
    for(Map<String, Double> ratesByDate : rates.values()){
        double baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency = ratesByDate.get(targetCurrency);
        if(rate == Double.MIN_VALUE ? baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency > rate : baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency < rate){
            rate = baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency;
        }
    }
    return rate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be the following: 
You give the function a rate, which either is `double.MIN_VALUE` or `double.MAX_VALUE` and call it `rate`. Within the function you could check if rate is `double.MIN_VALUE` or `double.MAX_VALUE`. Or just check if `rate` is smaller or bigger `baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency`. I am not quite sure if it is a constant or a not. This would be an example:

```
public double getCurrencyRateExtremaInTheCurrentMonth(String baseCurrency, String targetCurrency, double rate) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> rates = getAllRatesInCurrentMonth(baseCurrency);
    double resultRate = rate
    for(String key : rates.keySet()){
        Map<String, Double> ratesByDate = rates.get(key);
        double baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency = ratesByDate.get(targetCurrency);
        if((rate == double.MIN_VALUE && baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency > rate) || (rate == double.MAX_VALUE && baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency < rate)){
            resultRate = baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency;
        }
    }
    return resultRate;
}
```

I am assuming `baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency` has the same value as it is retrieved the same way within the function. Is that right?

Comment: `baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency > rate || baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency < rate` this condition is almost always true except for the case when `baseCurrecyRateToTargetCurrency == rate`. This won't really work.

Comment: @Amongalen, thank you for your comment. I updated my answer and check if rate is double.MIN or double.MAX first.

Comment: That still won't work. After the first iteration `rate` will change and the whole condition will always be false.